# In Jenkinsfile ./gradlew release doesn't execute because of a gitlab push fail

Tags: git, jenkins, kotlin, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

I am working on a java/kotlin project built using Gradle 4.1. I am using I am using GitLab for the source code, Jenkins(a multibranch pipeline project) for CI and Nexus as the repository for releases and snapshots. In addition, I am using the [axion-release-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin). In my project's Jenkinsfile, among other stages, I have a 'release' stage, in which I run the `./gradlew release` command. Other stages all run perfectly well, except 'release'(see the last stage in the code snippet from my Jenkinsfile provided below). The build fails while executing this command and the error is:

```
> Task :release FAILED
Task ':release' is not up-to-date because:
Task has not declared any outputs despite executing actions.
Creating tag: version-0.1.10
Pushing all to remote: origin
Exception occurred during push: 
org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: 
https://GITLAB/MY_REPO.git: not authorized
:release (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.821 
secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':release'.
> org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: 
https://GITLAB/MY_REPO.git: not authorized  

node {
```

I expect this error, since I am trying push without typing the username or password. I have looked at the [documentation page](http://axion-release-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) of the [axion-release-plugin](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin) and there seems to be very little information on how to push to the repo using **http://** link instead of **ssh**. When I follow the instructions from the documentation for authenticating with http, http://axion-release-plugin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/authorization.html#http-basic-auth-github-tokens and change the release stage to

```
 stage('release') {

      sh "./gradlew release -Prelease.customUsername= 'MYUSERNAME' -Prelease.customPassword= 'MYPASSWORD' -Prelease.disableChecks"
}
```

I get the following error:

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

 * What went wrong:
 Task 'MYUSERNAME' not found in root project 'MYPROJECT'.

 * Try:
 Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --debug 
 option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

 * Exception is:
 org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'MYUSERNAME' not found in 
 root project 'MYPROJECT'.
 at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:116)
```

Clearly, adding the password and username directly to the Jenkinsfile is not working, but I don't know where to get them from. 
I am wondering if anyone knows:

1. Where can I load the username and password from for my GitLab authentication?
2. How can I do that inside the `./gradlew release` command in the release stage?

My Jenkinsfile:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
node {

env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'jdk_current'}"

env.GRADLE_HOME="${tool 'gradle_current'}"

env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"

stage('checkout') {
    checkout scm 
}

....

stage('publish') {
    sh "./gradlew publish  --no-daemon --stacktrace"
}

stage('quality') {

   withSonarQubeEnv('FFAWS') {

    sh "./gradlew sonarqube --no-daemon "

    }
}
stage('upload') {
        sh "./gradlew upload --no-daemon --stacktrace "
}

stage('release') {

        sh "./gradlew release -Prelease.disableChecks -Prelease.pushTagsOnly --no-daemon --stacktrace "
}
```

Thank you! And feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: First, you have spaces between your Gradle properties on the command line - you should remove them - `-Prelease.customPassword='MYPASSWORD'`. If you want to use the SSH components to push to Git you may run into something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870282/git-inside-docker-inside-jenkins-pipeline-doesnt-work/47871209#47871209