# Using a secret for scm checkout from on-prem Bitbucket in a Jenkins pipeline in OpenShift

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, openshift

I'm trying to do an scm checkout from an on-prem Bitbucket server in a Jenkins pipeline in OpenShift.

I did all of the steps from [Private Git Repositories: Part 5 – Hosting Repositories on Bitbucket](https://blog.openshift.com/private-git-repositories-part-5-hosting-repositories-bitbucket/) so I have a public key in my Bitbucket repo and an annotated secret named `bitbucket` for the private key in OpenShift.

I found an example of how to do the scm checkout I have below in [this comment](https://github.com/openshift/jenkins-client-plugin/issues/116#issuecomment-362097453).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Template
metadata:
  name: service-gateway-pipeline
parameters:
- name: GIT_URL
  required: true
  value: 'ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7999/my-project/my-repo.git'
- name: GIT_BRANCH
  required: true
  value: 'master'
- name: BITBUCKET_WEBHOOK_SECRET
  description: BitBucket trigger secret
  from: '[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}'
  generate: expression
  required: true
- name: GENERIC_WEBHOOK_SECRET
  description: Generic build trigger secret
  from: '[a-zA-Z0-9]{8}'
  generate: expression
  required: true
objects:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: BuildConfig
  metadata:
    labels:
      app: dev
    name: dev
  spec:
    strategy:
      jenkinsPipelineStrategy:
        jenkinsfile: |-
          pipeline {
            options {
              timeout(time: 20, unit: 'MINUTES')
            }

            agent {
              node {
                label 'dotnet'
              }
            }

            stages {
              stage('Init') {
                steps {
                  sh 'oc whoami'
                }
              }
              stage('Checkout') {
                  steps {
                    script {
                      openshift.withCluster() {
                        openshift.withCredentials() { // also tried openshift.withCredentials('bitbucket')
                          openshift.withProject() {
                            checkout([$class           : 'GitSCM',
                                      branches         : [[name: "*/${GIT_BRANCH}"]],
                                      userRemoteConfigs: [[url: "${GIT_URL}"]]
                                      // also tried credentialsId: 'bitbucket'
                            ]);

                            dir("${WORKSPACE}") {
                                def commit_id = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD').trim()
                                echo "${commit_id}"
                            }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
    source:
      git:
        uri: ${GIT_URL}
        ref: ${GIT_BRANCH}
      sourceSecret:
        name: bitbucket
      type: Git
    triggers:
    - bitbucket:
        secret: dev-${BITBUCKET_WEBHOOK_SECRET}
      type: Bitbucket
    - generic:
        secret: dev-${GENERIC_WEBHOOK_SECRET}
      type: Generic
```

I apply the template like so `oc process -f pipeline-dev.yaml | oc apply -f -`

However, when I run the pipeline in OpenShift I get the error

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress ssh://git@bitbucket.example.com:7999/my-project/my-repo.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout:
stderr: Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I know from [this comment](https://github.com/openshift/origin/issues/13863#issuecomment-298813375) that

> ah, apparently we turn off strict host key checking when a private ssh key is provided.

So if I'm hitting the host key verification problem, clearly it's not picking up the credentials in any of the ways I tried in the pipeline template above.

Does anyone know how to specify the credentials in the pipeline such that Jenkins will use them in the checkout?

Comment: As you are doing a checkout from within a running pod, I suspect you actually need to use a build secret to mount an appropriate SSH key file into the ``.ssh`` directory. What is described in the blog post doesn't really apply in your case. See https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/builds/build_inputs.html#using-secrets-during-build

Comment: Might be worth checking that host key checking is definitely turned off see - https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871209/2961873

Comment: We are hitting the same problem.